# Best structure setup to resize tool using kineticjs

Tags: drag-and-drop, resize, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am making a drawing/designing tool in canvas using kineticjs library.

I can't figure out which is the best way for the objects structure order (groups, shapes, layers). 
I need to resize an object with dragging the selection nodes.

Here is what I have tried so far and the problem with it:
[image]

I have the rectangle (grey fill, black border) as the object I need to resize and I have the 8 selection nodes (brown rectangles). The problem with this setup is that rectangle needs to be draggable but the selection nodes must be positioned in the same time with the rectangle. So I have put all these in a single layer. The problem is that only layer can be draggable, not groups and shapes, so when I press the selection node to resize, it acts like I am dragging the whole layer.

What do you suggest, what setup should I use? 
Thanks!

Comment: @ Whoever voted to close:  Kindly remove the close vote.  This question is asking how to do a specific task ("How do I toggle Kinetic selectors on/off").  It's not a "What's the best..." question.  Thanks!  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your design permits, you can toggle the selector(s) on/off.

If the selector is OFF, the layer drags normally.

If the selector is ON (is resizing), dragging the selector resizes the rect.

**Here's one way to do that**

Add an "isResizing" flag to each selector:

```
selector1.isResizing=false;
```

Listen for click events on the selector and then toggle that selector ON/OFF:

```
selector1.on("click",function(e){
    this.isResizing = !this.isResizing;
});
```

When any selector turns ON:

```
layer.setDragging(false);
selector1.setDragging(true);
```

When any selector turns OFF:

```
layer.setDragging(true);
selector1.setDragging(false);
```

This way, when any selector turns ON you can listen to its dragmove events to resize the rect

Here is illustrating code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Y2m2z/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.2.min.js"></script>

<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    layer.setDraggable(true);
    stage.add(layer);

    var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x:50,
        y:50,
        width:100,
        height:100,
        fill: 'blue',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        draggable: false
    });
    layer.add(rect);

    var circle1 = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x:150,
        y:150,
        radius: 10,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        draggable: false
    });
    circle1.isResizing=false;
    circle1.on("click",function(e){
        // toggle resizing true/false
        var isResizing=!this.isResizing;
        this.setDraggable(isResizing);
        layer.setDraggable(!isResizing);
        this.setFill((isResizing?"green":"red"));
        this.isResizing=isResizing;
        layer.draw();
    });
    circle1.on("dragmove",function(){ 
        if(this.isResizing){
            var pos = this.getPosition();
            var x = pos.x;
            var y = pos.y;
            var rectX=rect.getX();
            var rectY=rect.getY();
                rect.setSize(x-rectX,y-rectY);
                layer.draw();
        }
    });
    layer.add(circle1);
    layer.draw();


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm new to Kineticjs. Wondering if this solution would work for image and text objects as well...

Comment: Nevermind. I played around with your fiddle and found out that it is possible with images. Haven't found out with text, but I'll play with that next. Here's an updated fiddle with image in case anybody wants it: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Y2m2z/

Answer (score 0):

Also to answer your original Question ---- I use....
(a stage obviously to hold everything, although you can have more than 1 stage it's actually confusing so don't).
(a layer to hold my static, unchanging background)
(a layer to hold my changing user interface)
(groups of objects that are clickable which I want to have similar effects happen on)

So. Stage - don't make more than 1.
Layer - have multiple, think of 'unchanging' vs 'stuff that is changing' and also 'what do I always want to keep in the frontmost layer' (ie: score) or whatever

My selection nodes are part of a group that contains the shape you are currently editing itself. By rule, all shapes are part of a group. Even if the group only contains 1 item.

So far it's worked out good for me.